# I am trying to write an SQL Query to extract the brands purchased by the customers? I have tried joining the tables but I am not able to execute it

Tags: mysql, sql

Here I have tried to inner join the table but I am unable to execute it properly

```
SELECT brand_name.Production,
FROM Production
INNER JOIN Sales ON Production.brand_id=Sales.brand_id;
```

I am fairly new to SQL, please guide me through.

[image]

Comment: Your published query does not have any joins please add your attempt in full

Comment: And read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: What is your expected out put, you have not joined any thing in question

Comment: Hi Shibon, What are the brands purchased by the customers?, I need a query for this

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure in text form, sample input data, the expected output, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: As it's a homework question I'm not going to supply an answer - Research JOINS read your course notes and publish your query attempt (with joins) The path to brands seems customer>>orders>>order_items>>products>>brands

Comment: What's your problem,via robin

Comment: Hi Salmon, please help me with this, I am researching with this but I cannot come up with  a solution

Comment: Your attempt so far was `Select * from Customers`??? That is all? You say you tried to join the tables and that failed. Please show this query.

Comment: Are sales and production two distinct databases/schemas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make subqueries to select,in order:the orders the customer made from the orders table using order_id,then you need to select the products he purchased from the products table using product_id,then the brand of the product from the brands table using brand_id and from the brands table you can select the name of the brands. The queries should look something like this:

```
SELECT brands.brand_name
FROM brands
WHERE brands.brand_id IN (SELECT products.brand_id 
                                    FROM products 
                                    WHERE product_id IN(SELECT order_items.product_id
                                                                FROM order_items
                                                                WHERE order_id IN (SELECT orders.order_id FROM orders WHERE customer_id IN ('Insert query to find whatever id you want')
```

Comment: Hello Emanuele, thanks for answering, just one more doubt, if I have to find the brands purchased by customers I just need to write customers in place of 'Insert query to find whatever id you want', thanks in advance

Comment: There appear to be 2 databases/schemas in the diagram sales and production so table names may need to be qualified accordingly.

Comment: If I need to count how many customers purchased each brand, I just have to add COUNT before brand.brand_name? right?

Comment: Also if I have to Categorize the customers according to the following: Their last name; A to D, E to H, I to L, M to Q, R to U, and V to Z, where do I do it

Comment: You should define the customers you are trying to find in that query yes,probably with a select statement depending on the request.

Comment: To count you should use the COUNT functions yes,but be careful, it's probably better to count ids because they are unique,while names could be recurring

Comment: I don't understand the last question, do you want to categorize only customers' names from the customers table?If so you should add a WHERE  clause and use REGEXP '^[A-D]' or whatever starting letters you want back